# Java: Are generic ArrayLists faster than LinkedLists for iteration?

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity

For an ArrayList of a particular type, we can find the size of object (of a particular type) in the ArrayList, and directly access the object at any index in O(1). This is because object references are stored in contiguous chunk of memory in ArrayList, and hence by skipping `object_size * index` memory locations, we access the memory location where the reference of desired object is residing. 
Whereas, in LinkedList, we would have to iterate through each object till we reach the desired object. 
For a generic ArrayList, containing different types of objects (with varying sizes), is `get(index i)` done in O(1)? If so, how?

Comment: The ArrayList stores object references, not the object data itself.

Comment: What does generics have to do with anything?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, thanks edited the question.

Comment: @shmosel I suspect OP means "generic" in the generic sense, not in the Java sense.

Comment: My point is that object references are all the same size, no matter the size of the object it refers to.

Comment: Right, thanks!
That answers it.

Comment: get(index) is faster for ArrayLists than LinkedLists but if you are iterating over the list it is big O(n) for both Array and Linked Lists.  The iterator will remember last position and each step will be O(1).  It is only if you do a indexed for loop that LinkedLists become slower.  The foreach loop or a while with iterator is O(n) for both types of lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You working under a misconception.  Objects are not stored in arrays, only *references* (i.e. pointers) to objects are stored in the array.  Objects themselves are on the  heap.  Therefore finding a specific object in an `ArrayList` by index will always be `O(1)` regardless of what it contains, and a `LinkedList` will be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your question, but it might be useful to consider the Apache commons-collection: **FastArrayList**

Giving it an initial capacity:

```
List<Integer> listOfLength = new FastArrayList(256);
    
for (String block : arrayOfBlocks) {
    listOfLength.add(block.length());
}
```